# Spring - How can I compare values from JSP form to values in db? (Service+DAO)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm making a web application (Virtual Clinic)I made DAO and Service layers (I'm beginner at it) for that and it works fine in Controller, but I don't know how can I compare `@ModelAttribute("user") User user` to values (login, password) which are in db, I want in order to application will redirect to Home.jsp if entered values are in database, if not - then app will redirect to different jsp. Could somebody show me how should I do it properly?

Here is a code:

LoginController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView homePagePost(@ModelAttribute("user") User user)
{   
    setAppContext();         
    clinicService.checkAuthentication(user);     

    ModelAndView home = new ModelAndView("Home");
    return home;
}
```

Login.jsp:

```
<form action="/VirtualClinic/home.html" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login"/>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

UserDaoImpl:

```
public void checkAuthentication(User user) {
    String query = "SELECT login, password FROM virtualclinic.user WHERE login=? AND password=?";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, user.getLogin());
        ps.setString(2, user.getPassword());
        ResultSet out = ps.executeQuery();

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }// TODO Auto-generated met

}
```

ClinicServiceImpl:

```
public void checkAuthentication(User user) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clinicconfig.xml");
    userDAO = ctx.getBean("userDAO", UserDAO.class);

    user.setLogin(user.getLogin());
    user.setPassword(user.getPassword());

    userDAO.checkAuthentication(user);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

diff the two bean, here is an implementation:

```
public static List<ChangeItem> getChangeItems(Object oldObj, Object newObj) {
        Class cl = oldObj.getClass();
        List<ChangeItem> changeItems = new ArrayList<ChangeItem>();

        try {
            BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(cl, Object.class);

            for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : beanInfo
                    .getPropertyDescriptors()) {
                String fieldname = propertyDescriptor.getName();
                String oldProp = getValue(PropertyUtils.getProperty(oldObj,
                        fieldname));
                String newProp = getValue(PropertyUtils.getProperty(newObj,
                        fieldname));

                if (!oldProp.equals(newProp)) {
                    ChangeItem changeItem = new ChangeItem();
                    changeItem.setField(fieldname);
                    changeItem.setNewValue(newProp);
                    changeItem.setOldValue(oldProp);
                    changeItems.add(changeItem);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("There is error when convert changeset", e);
        }

        return changeItems;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the below changes to make it work.

1) Add a string return type to method `checkAuthentication` in the class `ClinicServiceImpl.java`, to identify whether login is `"success"` or `"failure"`.

2) Based on this return value in the `LoginController.java` you can redirect to the appropriate page.

3) In the `checkAuthentication` method of `UserDaoImpl` class, you need to check whether any record exist in the DB with the input value username and password.

Code should be as below:

**LoginController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView homePagePost(@ModelAttribute("user") User user)
{   
    setAppContext();         
    String result = clinicService.checkAuthentication(user);     

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    if("success".equals(result)) {
       mav.setViewName("Home"); 
    } else {
       mav.setViewName("Login");
    }       
    return mav;
}
```

**ClinicServiceImpl.java:**

```
public String checkAuthentication(User user) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clinicconfig.xml");
    userDAO = ctx.getBean("userDAO", UserDAO.class);

    user.setLogin(user.getLogin());
    user.setPassword(user.getPassword());

    String result = userDAO.checkAuthentication(user);
    return result;
}
```

**UserDaoImpl:**

```
public String checkAuthentication(User user) {
    String query = "SELECT login, password FROM virtualclinic.user WHERE login=? AND password=?";
    String result = null;
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, user.getLogin());
        ps.setString(2, user.getPassword());
        ResultSet out = ps.executeQuery();
        out.last();
        int count  = out.getRow();
        if(count==1) {
           result = "success";
        } else {
           result = "failure";
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }// TODO Auto-generated met
    return result;
}
```